# Genesis 1:1-3 Creator of the heavens and the earth?

Tags: creation, trinity

When I was reading Genesis 1, I noticed something interesting:

> Genesis 1:1-3 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth...and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters. And God said...

Here it seems three persons of the trinity have already appeared; the Father, the Spirit, and the Son (Word). But only in creating the heavens and the earth, it's stated that merely God "created". The remainder of Chapter 1 is "And God said..." and God created or made this and that afterward.

And then, John says in his gospel:

> John 1:3 Through him all things were made; without him nothing was made that has been made.

So the Word was the creator and the Spirit also participated in creating. But what about Father? Did the absence of "And God said..." imply that only the Father was in charge of creating the heavens and earth.

I'm just a student so I scarcely know anything about Hebrew. If someone can use language differences to explain, I will much appreciate it.

Comment: The term in Heb "elohim" (= God) is plural as seen in Gen 1:26, etc.

Comment: Does the Hebrew elohim indicate the number of Creator, if by plural you mean more than one? How many Creators are there if elohim is plural 2?3?. 5?

Comment: This question should be closed, it is not about the text at all.

Answer (score 2):

### Translation of Genesis 1:1

A literal translation of Genesis 1:1 might be something like this:

"In beginning, created God [DOM] the heavens and [DOM] the earth."

DOM = direct object marker in Hebrew which is not translated to English, but means the next word is a direct object of the verb.

The word "God" is from "elohim," which is a word of plural form in Hebrew just like the words "scissors" and "physics" are plural in English.  It is only possible to know whether the word is plural in grammatical construction based on the verbs and adjectives used with it.

### Hebrew Grammar for Nouns

Hebrew nouns have both number and gender, like nouns of most Latin languages, e.g. Spanish.  If you know Spanish, for example, you will understand that the word "idioma," which means "language," is of feminine form, because it has the feminine suffix.  But when this word is actually used, a Spanish reader will quickly see that it is actually masculine, because it is preceded by the masculine article "el" instead of by the feminine "la."

Hebrew is the same.  In order to know the number and the gender of nouns, because there are actually many exceptions, one must look at the adjectives and verbs, which indicate both the number and the gender.

In Genesis 1:1, the verb is "created."  This verb is in singular form, showing that "elohim" is a singular noun.

Hebrew has many nouns that might always appear in a plural word form but whose number will vary according to the verbs and adjectives.  For example, the Hebrew word "faces" is always of plural form, but that hardly means everyone has two faces.  In fact, in Genesis 1:2, we have the word "faces" in Hebrew--used to describe the surface of the "waters," which, by the way, is also always plural in form in Hebrew.  "Heavens" from verse 1 is another word that is always plural in Hebrew, yet it is translated in many versions as "heaven" because, even though the noun would seem to be plural, there is no adjective or verb used with this object in this case, meaning the translators cannot be certain if it should be singular or plural.

### Grammatical Applications

The verb "created" being singular, we *know* that "God" is singular in Genesis 1:1, which is why it is not translated as "Gods."

So in Genesis 1:1, God is singular--there is no Trinity here.

In Genesis 1:2 we see a reference to "the spirit of God."  This comes from a Hebrew construct chain in which the two nouns "spirit" and "gods" (remember, "elohim" is always plural in form) occur together.  The preposition "of" is supplied in English as a necessary translation of the Hebrew meaning, but no "of" exists in Hebrew here.  Both of the words "ruach" (spirit) and the word "elohim" (gods) are non-definite in Hebrew.  In English we would call them both common nouns, as opposed to proper.  Because they are both equal in definiteness, Hebrew grammar places them in a "construct chain," having a *belonging* relationship, which is why "of" is necessarily supplied in the English translation.  The verb ("hovered") which follows is in singular form, which means "elohim" is not plural, but rather is singular.

Again, in Genesis 1:2 there is no plural for "God" used--it is singular, and there is no grammatical support for a Trinity.

### Who Created Us?

> Have we not all **one father**? hath not **one God** created us? why do we
> deal treacherously every man against his brother, by profaning the
> covenant of our fathers? (Malachi 2:10, KJV)
>
> Thus saith **God the LORD, he** that created the heavens, and
> stretched them out; **he** that spread forth the earth, and that which
> cometh out of it; **he** that giveth breath unto the people upon it,
> and spirit to them that walk therein: (Isaiah 42:5, KJV)

Malachi 3:10 uses a couplet to suggest that our "one father" is also our "one God," and Isaiah 42:5 names him.  The KJV "the LORD" is a poor translation: "Jehovah" would be better, as this is actually God's name in Hebrew.

Note that God does not have three names, is never said to be three, and the pronoun "he" is singular: "them" is never used for God in the Bible.

### Conclusion

The popular notion of "elohim" representing a plural for God is false, as a study of Hebrew grammar reveals.  God's spirit is just that--His spirit.  It is not a separate God, nor a separate being.  Jesus taught that "God is a spirit" (see John 4:24), so it is natural to refer to his presence at the creation as a spirit.  Yes, God's "word" spoke creation into existence: yet nothing about Genesis 1:1-3 addresses this word as if it were a person or entity separate from God.  Ultimately, Genesis 1:1-3 cannot be used to support a Trinity.

Comment: "So in Genesis 1:1, God is singular--there is no Trinity here." My fellow trinitarians would argue that a mixture of plural and singular is entirely appropriate for the trinity. There is only one God (singular), with a plurality of persons in Him (plural). Your argument would rule out tritheism, but trinitarianism isn't tritheism.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus was there. God said: be light! John says:In him was life; and the life was the light of men.John 1:4 and Jesus said in John 8:12...Then spake Jesus again unto them, saying, I am the light of the world.... Look also to: Proverbs 8...22The LORD possessed me in the beginning of his way, before his works of old.

23I was set up from everlasting, from the beginning, or ever the earth was.

24When there were no depths, I was brought forth; when there were no fountains abounding with water.

25Before the mountains were settled, before the hills was I brought forth:

26While as yet he had not made the earth, nor the fields, nor the highest part of the dust of the world.

27When he prepared the heavens, I was there: when he set a compass upon the face of the depth:

28When he established the clouds above: when he strengthened the fountains of the deep:

29When he gave to the sea his decree, that the waters should not pass his commandment: when he appointed the foundations of the earth:

30Then I was by him, as one brought up with him: and I was daily his delight, rejoicing always before him;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SivJorunnUllvang. What does brought forth mean in Proverbs 8 :25?

Comment: I try…To bear, bring fort, beget. By Father (Bibel site). God did that by making the light. (Jesus) Genesis 1. 3. The sun came in vers 14 when God said: Let there be lights in the firmament …

Comment: It all started with the light and it ended with the light. Revelations 22:4-5

Answer (score -1):

The scriptures are clear that the one True God created everything:

Isaiah 44:24 (NASB95)

> Thus says the LORD, your Redeemer, and the one who formed you from the womb, “I, the LORD, am the maker of all things, Stretching out the heavens by Myself And spreading out the earth all alone.

When it comes to the New Testament, we are told in various passages that the Son (Jesus) is the creator of everything.

John 1:3 (NASB95)

> All things came into being through Him, and apart from Him nothing came into being that has come into being.

Colossians 1:15-17 (NASB95)

> He is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of all creation. For by Him all things were created, both in the heavens and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities—all things have been created through Him and for Him. He is before all things, and in Him all things hold together.

In other passages, we are told that the Father created everything through the Son:

Hebrews 1:2 (NASB95)

> in these last days has spoken to us in His Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, through whom also He made the world.

In the Old Testament, we are told that the Holy Spirit also had a role in the creation:

Genesis 1:2 (NASB95)

> The earth was formless and void, and darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was moving over the surface of the waters.

So to answer your question, No, the Father did not only create the heavens and earth, he created everything through the Son, and the Spirit had a role in the creation too, but the role of the Spirit is not specified in the New Testament like how the Son's role is specified in details.

We are told that the Son (Jesus) had the direct role in creation (He laid the foundations of the earth and the heavens are the works of his hands), this is the Father speaking to the Son (see Hebrews 1:8 onward):

Hebrews 1:10 (NASB95)
And, “YOU, LORD, IN THE BEGINNING LAID THE FOUNDATION OF THE EARTH, AND THE HEAVENS ARE THE WORKS OF YOUR HANDS; THEY WILL PERISH, BUT YOU REMAIN; AND THEY ALL WILL BECOME OLD LIKE A GARMENT,

Which is quoted directly from Psalms 102:25 which was directed to Yahweh himself.

To summarise, the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit were involved in the creation but the New Testament tells us that it is the Son the one who accomplished the work of creation and the Father said "Let there be", to make it easier for your, the Father commanded and the Son accomplished, and of course with the involvement of the Holy Spirit.

EDIT to answer OP's follow-up question:

I believe you are comparing it with Genesis 1:3 "Then God said, “Let there be light”; and there was light.".

"God created" = God's act of creation, and, "God said let there be and there was" = God's act of creation, when I'm speaking of the Son accomplishing the creation, I'm not speaking of a separate deity/god, I'm speaking of the one True God, one with the Father.

Saying the Father created the heaven and earth is not wrong and saying the Son created the heaven and earth is not wrong either, but when speaking about the nature of God in specifics, the Father created the heaven and earth through the Son, another thing to note is that Genesis 1:1 started with God's accomplishment of the creation of the heaven and earth, so possibly, the event of God saying "Let there be heaven and earth" could have taken place before the event of Genesis 1:1.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139886/discussion-on-answer-by-isha-genesis-11-3-creator-of-the-heavens-and-the-earth).

Comment: @Isha. Who is the one true God that you say is one with the Father?

Answer (score -2):

Genesis chapter one shows us that triadic structure is the foundation of the universe. Because God is triadic, everything is formed and sustained based on this divine triadic pattern. Everything we do, every action we take, and everything we relate to in this world is governed triadically. We cannot even pick up a rock without triadic structure. All of creation reveals the three-fold evidence of triadic structure of intelligent design, active cause, and organization.

There must be a source of causation in the eternal realm that is able to bring its power to bear upon the world of matter to create it, organize it, and sustain it. This first requires an intelligence that is capable of formulating ideas. Since ideas are abstracts existing only within the mind, they cannot be realized until they are given substantive existence. How did creation begin? It began as an idea in the mind of the First Position. Realization of the idea required the exercise of power and will to give form to the idea. This was the actual creation of matter. This also required power and wisdom to organize matter into an isomorphic state with the idea. This is organization. Creation began in the mind of the First Position as a set of abstractions. These abstractions were relayed by command to the Second Position who brought his will to bear upon those ideas. By the exercise of power, he brought matter into existence. This is what we are told in Colossians 1:16-17, Hebrews 1:10, and John 1:3.

The Third Position functions as the indexical agent. He brought both worlds together into a single reality. The Third Position brought order to the universe. He organized the matter that was created by the Second Position so that it conformed precisely to the idea in the mind of the First Position. In the creation account, he established continuity between the celestial bodies to keep them in a state of mutual synchronization. He established boundaries for the heavens and the earth. He created a symbiotic relationship between the earth and all living creatures. He then set in motion a system of temporal measurements to govern the seasons. He then appointed man as the representational figure of God to govern the natural world. Now, man must stand in the indexical position of a different triad and learn how to link his material existence in the world to the will and power of the Creator (we will look at this later in chapter six). Man must rule over that which God had made according to the design of divine will.

In Genesis 1:1, the writer introduces us to God. God is presented to us in the Hebrew as the Elohim. Elohim is the plural form of the noun El that we translate as God. From the beginning then, we learn that creation was a joint effort with each member operating within his own dynamic function. Notice how this is portrayed in each creative event.

1. The creation of the heavens and the earth – “In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth.”

a.  What we are seeing here is the formation of the periodic table. Matter was brought into existence. This was Second Position function which forced an idea into material form. The state of the earth at that point was shapeless, empty, dark, and aquatic. Then…

b.  “The Spirit of God moved (or brooded) over the face of the waters.”

This was Third Position function. (The waters here seem to represent an embryonic shroud for the earth. This same symbolism is seen in the crossing of the Red Sea by the Israelites and again in the act of baptism). We are not told exactly what the Spirit of God was doing to the earth. What we are told is that the Spirit was the one who was preforming the function. The result of that function appears to have been the organization or the earth into a place suited to the needs of all the life forms that were about to be placed upon it.

2. The creation of light, 3-5

a.  God said, “Let there be light.”
This is a relay of idea in the form of command. This is First Position function. Since a command is given, there must of necessity, be a recipient. Someone must function to execute the command.

b.  “And there was light.”
The idea is now given material form. Execution of command is Second Position function.

c.  Light was then organized and assigned specific function. Organization is Third Position function. He separated it from the darkness, named it, and assigned it as a temporal indicator, and evening and morning was designated as the first day.

3. The creation of the expanse, 6-8

a.  God said, “Let there be an expanse in the midst of the waters.” This is First Position function of idea/command.

b.  “And God made the expanse,” This is Second Position function of active cause. The idea was acted upon and given material form.

c.  It was then separated and named. This is Third Position function of organization.

4. The separation of the waters from the land, 9-10

a.  God said, “Let the waters be gathered into one place and let the dry land appear.” This is First Position function of command.

b.  “It was so.” The Second Position function was forced onto the world of matter and matter responded.

c.  Function was assigned. This is Third Position function of organization. Dry land was called earth and the gathering of waters he called seas.

5. The formation of botanical life, 11-13

a.  God said, “Let the earth sprout vegetation.” This is First Position function of command.

b.  “And it was so.” Second Position function again gave form to the idea.

c.  Organization is assigned. This is Third Position function. It was assigned to produce fruit after its kind.

6. The formation of the celestial bodies, 14-19

a.  God said, “Let there be lights in the expanse.” This is First Position function of command.

b.  “And it was so.” Celestial light was formed. This is Second Position function of active cause.

c.  They were then organized and assigned specific functions. This is Third Position function. He separated day and night. He appointed them to serve as temporal indicators of the seasons and to give light upon the earth.

7. The formation of marine and avian life, 20-22

a.  God said, “Let the waters team with swarms of living creatures and let birds fly above the earth.” This is First Position function of command.

b.  “And God created.” This is Second Position function of active cause.

c.  “And God blessed them.” This is Third Position function of organization. He assigned function. He commanded them to be fruitful, to multiply, and to fill the waters. He commanded the birds to multiply upon the earth.

8. The creation of land creatures, 24-25

a.  God said, “Let the earth bring forth living creatures.” Again, this is First Position function of command.

b.  “And it was so.” Second Position function of active cause – He made it happen.

c.  They were then organized after their kind. This is Third Position function.

9. The creation of man, 26-30

a.  God said, “Let us make man in our image, according to our likeness.” The First Position gave instruction as to the kind of being man was to be.

b.  “And God created man in his own image” This is Second Position function of active cause. He carried out the command.

c.  “God blessed them.” This is Third Position function of organization. He commanded man to be fruitful, to multiply, to fill the earth, to bring it under control, to cultivate it, and rule over everything that God had made. God saw that all that he had made was very good. Triadic unity became the pattern for the creation and formation of everything in the natural dimension.

(Glen Rogers author)

Comment: This answer is as non-sensical/Biblical as the Q.

Comment: @oldhermit. Where did base your "God is triadic" statement?